# How do I find c such that the probability that a Chi-squared random variable lies in the interval [0,c] is smaller than 1/2

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gamma-function, chi-squared

I have the following problem. Given i.i.d. standard Gaussian random variables $x_i$ with mean $0$ and variance $1$. We compute $X=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$. Find $c$ such that $\Pr(c\geq X)\leq 1/2$.

I know that $X$ is a chi squared random variable with $n$ degrees of freedom. The probability that $X$ lies in an interval $[0,c]$ is therefore given by the distribution function which is in this case $F_n(y)=P(n/2, y/2)$ where $P$ is the incomplete Gamma function. Hence I have to find $c$ such that $P(n/2, c/2) \leq 1/2$. Unfortunately the incomplete Gamma function is (for me) hard to handle and I am stuck on how to explicitly compute this $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

The density function of $\ X\ $ is bounded above by $\ \frac{x^{\frac{n}{2}-1}}{2^\frac{n}{2}\Gamma\big(\frac{n}{2}\big)}\ $, so
$$
P\big(c\ge X\big)\le\frac{1}{2^\frac{n}{2}\Gamma\big(\frac{n}{2}\big)}\int_0^cx^{\frac{n}{2}-1}dx\ .
$$

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. With this one is able to compute: $P(c>=X)<=1/(n \Gamma(n/2))2^{1-n/2}c^{n/2}$. Solving this equation yields $c\leq 2^{1-2/n}n^{2/n}\Gamma(n/2)^{2/n}$ and therefore my desired constraint for $c$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. I've only checked your algebra by eye, but I didn't pick up any slips.

Comment: Great! Thank you !